# How to install pydantic_core in Pythonista?

Tags: pip, pydantic, pythonista

I want to install pydantic_core package in Pythonista app on iOS.

I have installed stash in Pythonista. Than I run stash and do:
pip install pydantic_core

I get the following error message:

```
15:03 Sun 31 Mar
StaSh
Console
stash: `C
KeyboardInterrupt: Exit: 0

StaSh v0.7.5 on python 3.10.4
Warning: you are running StaSh in python3. Some commands may not work correctly in python3.
Please help us improve StaSh by reporting bugs on github.
Tip: Improve script-compatibility with the monkeylord command
[~/Documents]$ pip install pydantic_core
site-packages/stash/bin/pip.py:35: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
  from distutils.util import convert_path
Querying PyPI ...
Downloading package ...
Opening: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/2a/af32a000af1affa8998a442d79841f4ad1a6408cc8ca0c00a5be2390124677f/
pydantic_core-2.17.0.tar.gz
Save as: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/24B05C11-9B6C-439F-A409-20E212C33565/tmp/pydantic_core-2.17.0.tar.gz
(379628 bytes)
[==================================================] 100.00% | 370.7KiB
stash: `C
KeyboardInterrupt: Exit: 0

Extracting archive file ...
Archive extracted.
Running setup file ...
FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
Failed to run setup.py
Fall back to directory guessing ...
Error: Cannot locate packages. Manual installation required.
stash: `C
KeyboardInterrupt: Exit: 1

[~/Documents]$
```

Any ideas how to make it work? I was able to install some other packages like ‘openai’ ‘type_extensions’ and ‘pedantic’ using stash and ‘pip install’.